# Task list using inplview.aspx in projectsites but not teamsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, task-list

When I create a new PROJECTsite using the standard Projectsite template, the Tasks webpart on the homepage automatically opens in Quickedit mode.

From my research I understood that a call is made to inplview.aspx which also adds some items to the querystring:

```
#InplviewHashbcd031e1-0c9a-411a-911b-914a6e114dc8=CascDelWarnMessage%3D1-ShowInGrid%3DTrue
```

On the other hand, which I create a new TEAMsite using the standard Teamsite template, add a Tasks lists and add a Tasks webpart on the homepage it does NOT automatically open in Quickedit mode (i.e. it is not using inplview.aspx)

I would prefer that the Tasks webpart in the Projectsite does NOT automatically open in Quickedit mode. How could I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, you have two options:

1. Edit the page AllItems.aspx >> Edit the Tasks Webpart >> Activate
   `Server Render` in the `Miscellaneous` section. When you do that you
   lose your toolbar and the ECB, though.
2. Use the script below to exit the Quickedit mode automatically.

---

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    ExitGrid(ctx.view);
  }, 0);
}, "spgantt.js");
```

I'm not really sure what causes the task list's AllItems-view to open in Quickedit mode by default. So, maybe there's a simpler way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I've tested both solutions and they do work fine. I like the javascript solution best, although the edit mode is still noticably visible before being closed by the script. Before accepting this as the answer, I'll wait for a bit too see if an even better solution and possible an explanation comes up.